# Z test for paired proportions when only the two proportions are available

Tags: proportion, z-test

I am familiar with formulae for paired proportions Z test when the crosstabs table is available. However, if only the two proportions are available, I am having trouble to figure out what is the S.E. of the $P_1 - P_2$.

If the following crosstab is available

|  | Success | Failure | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sucess | a | b | a+b |
| Failure | c | d | c+d |
| Total | a+c | b+d | n |

Then the test $H_0: \pi_{a+b}=\pi_{a+b}$ is equivalent to $H_0: \pi_{b}=\pi_{c}$.
The test statistic, e.g. Agresti and Wing, May & Johson, 1997, can be written as

$$
Z_1=\frac{\hat P_{b} - \hat P_{c}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{P}_{b}+\hat{P}_{c} -(\hat P_{b} -\hat P_{c})^2}{n}}}\\
Z_1 = \dfrac{b-c}{\sqrt{(b+c)-\dfrac{(b-c)^2}{n}}} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$
This obvioulsy requires that $b$ and $c$ are known.

What if, I only have $\hat P_1=\frac{a+b}{n}$ and $\hat P_2=\frac{a+c}{n}$ and the total $n$ and need to test $H_0: P_1=P_2$?
I would say that the test Statistic would be
$$ 
Z_2=\dfrac{\hat P_1-\hat P_2}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat P_{1}+\hat P_{2}-(\hat P_1-\hat P_2)^2}{n}}}
$$

Since testing $P_1=P_2$ is equal to test $P_b=P_c$, I would say that $Z_1$ would be equal to $Z_2$, but it is not, and I can figure out what noob mistake I am making.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Ref: May,W.L.& Johnson,W.D.(1997).Validity and power of tests for equality of two correlated proportions.Statistics in Medicine,16(10):1081–1096.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is similar to McNemar's test (which might be a helpful reference), where, yes, you need to know *b* and *c*.  If you don't have those, logically, you can't treat the data as "paired" in that manner.  You can't logically know if e.g. from *before* to *after* more observations changed from "Success" to "Failure" as the reverse, without *b* and *c*.

Comment: Near the end of your post, you write that *P1 = (a+b)/n* and *P2 = (a+c)/n*. I suspect you have something mistyped here.  Do you mean e.g. *a/(a+b)* for one of these ?  And should the second proportion be based on *c* and *d*, and not *a* and *c* ?

Comment: No, I really mean P1 as being the proportion of Success at time 1 and P2 as being the proportion of success at time 2. For example, P1 - proportion of depressed patients before intervention; P2 - proportion of depressed patients after terapy-